# Webform validation Drupal

Tags: validation, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm looking to add some speacial validation with webform through Drupal. It seems the old forms you could add extra PHP code to "Advanced Settings". According to this [link](http://drupal.org/node/754580) we shouldn't be doing this anymore. (Running Drupal 6)

What I have is a check box that makes a few fields disappear and a few different fields appears. So for my validation I need to validate only the fields that are "present" depending on if the checkbox is checked or not. (Make them disappear/reappear with JQuery). The last step is to change the validation code.

I looked into the webform validation module, but it doesn't seem to hold what I need since I can't specify specific fields based on a checkbox.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hook_form_alter you can add your own validation handler to the webform where you can validate the data as you like.

Comment: it might not be obvious to the poster, but this would cause the validation to be checked on the server, any clientside validation would still be in effect.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to drupal, I'll look into the hook_form_alter. Thanks! Does the current webform validation occur on the server side or client side?

Comment: I wrote the hook_form_alter, but I can't seem to get any vlaues from the $form_values? $form_values['submitted_tree']['Name']['Name'] comes back as nothing? Any suggestions if anybody is still listening :p

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional module? (requires webform ver 3). It avoids the use of custom jquery and might work better better with webform validation module.